How does base change affect group schemes?
I am reading through Waterhouse's Introduction to Affine Group Schemes and am having trouble understanding how I should think of base change as it relates to the way a groups scheme "looks".
In particular, for any base ring $k$ and a homomorphism $k \to k'$ we can restrict the group functor $G$ to $G_{k'}$ since any $k'$-algebra $S$ is also a $k$-algebra by $k \to k' \to S$. Moreover, if $G$ is represented by $A$ we have that
$$\hom_{k'-alg}(A \otimes_{k}k',S) \simeq \hom_{k-alg}(A,S).$$
This means that $G_{k'}$ is represented by $A \otimes_{k}k'$.
Thus, I have two questions,

If the $k'$-algebra maps are the same as the $k$-algebra maps, what has actually changed about the group scheme? For example, if we consider $\mathbf{G}_m(S)$ for some $k'$-algebra $S$, which is all invertible elements of $S$, how is this different than $(\mathbf{G}_m ) _{k'}(S)$?

In the case of finite constant groups $G$, we can talk about it's Cartier dual. It's dual, $G^D$, is given by $G^D(R) = (G_R)^D(R)$. In particular we get that $G^D(R) \simeq \hom(G_R,(G_m)_R)$. Is this $\hom$ as $k$-algebra homomorphisms? As in, are we viewing $A\otimes R$ as a $k$-algebra and looking at the group characters over $k$, or over $R$?


Thank you.

For the first question, the maps have to respect the structure maps. If k is Q(sqrt(2)) vs C, the maps for an algebraic group on C would likely be different since there are multiple morphisms of the former to C, but a unique map of C to C (choosing a base field essentially says no internal automorphisms of k are allowed). For visualizing group schemes, I like to think of the scheme and having the group "living over it" which can be pulled back by morphisms, like classifying spaces in topology. Changing base is then pulling back the classifying space to the "setting" of the other field.
